# Консоль Windows

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-basic, .net

Здравствуйте . Есть задача -  работа с консолью (выполнение команд и получение ответа)
Есть ли в VB.NET класс для работы с консолью ? Чтобы обойтись **БЕЗ** Shell и Process.

Comment: Имеется ввиду командная строка Windows

Comment: А почему не подходит Shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы используете проект консольного приложения смотрите в сторону класса Console

Comment: Имеется ввиду командная строка Windows